# simple_form 'form-inline' not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, slim-lang

I'm trying to make two input (firstname and lastname) to next to each other.

Here is my code and it's currently just showing two big rows of input window.

```
= simple_form_for @user, html: {class: 'form-inline'} do |f|
  = f.fields_for :profile, @user.profile || Profile.new, html: {class: 'form-inline'}  do |p|
     .form-1
        .form-1-detail
           .input-text
              = f.input :last_name, required: true
           .input-text
               = f.input :first_name, required: true
```

I'm now sure how to make them to display inline. Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

> Updated. This is the actual HTML generate from

```
= simple_form_for @user, html: {class: 'form-inline'} do |f|
 = f.fields_for :profile, @user.profile || Profile.new do |p| # removed form-inline here
  .form-1
    .form-1-detail
      .form-group
        = f.input :last_name, required: true
      .form-group
        = f.input :first_name, required: true




</div><form class="simple_form form-inline" novalidate="novalidate" id="new_user" action="/users" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="DhQSodBk8kxdE6q9uPJDKSs9FfxCNLyXFYT3bZ42HlZfHefxfG3BDq9qkFpxkX7MBZI4Mc4Wje6LKw7Gp1YcjQ==" />
  <div class="form-1">
    <div class="form-1-detail">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input string required user_last_name"><label class="string required" for="user_last_name"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> 姓</label><input class="string required" placeholder="姓" type="text" name="user[last_name]" id="user_last_name" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input string required user_first_name"><label class="string required" for="user_first_name"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> 名</label><input class="string required" placeholder="名" type="text" name="user[first_name]" id="user_first_name" /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div></form>
```

Answer (score 9):

You should install the simple_form wrappers:

```
rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap
```

From there you can structure a inline_form using it's corresponding wrapper:

```
simple_form_for @user, wrapper: :inline_form, html: { class: 'form-inline' } ...
```

They have an example app: https://github.com/rafaelfranca/simple_form-bootstrap

The specific view that using this is (sorry it's ERB however):

https://github.com/rafaelfranca/simple_form-bootstrap/blob/master/app/views/examples/_inline_form_sf.html.erb

Answer (score 1):

Try using `f.input_field` instead of `f.input`.

Reference: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#stripping-away-all-wrapper-divs

Answer (score 0):

The `simple_form` gem uses Bootstrap, right? I compared your code to the [Bootstrap Form docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline) and I think you should be using `form-group` classes inside the `form-inline`.

```
= simple_form_for @user, html: {class: 'form-inline'} do |f|
  = f.fields_for :profile, @user.profile || Profile.new do |p| # removed form-inline here
   .form-1
      .form-1-detail
         .form-group
            = f.input :last_name, required: true
         .form-group
            = f.input :first_name, required: true
```

Alternatively, unless you have unique CSS that you need to apply for the `form-1` and `form-1-detail` classes, this might be able to be shortened to:

```
= simple_form_for @user, html: {class: 'form-inline'} do |f|
  = f.fields_for :profile, @user.profile || Profile.new do |p| # removed form-inline here
     .form-group
        = f.input :last_name, required: true
     .form-group
        = f.input :first_name, required: true
```

If that doesn't work, can you post the actual HTML that is generated for the form in the browser?

Comment: Thank you for posting. I tried both of then and it's still the same. I posted actual HTML generated by your first suggestion.

Comment: You have to add the wrapper parameter to simple_form_for, otherwise the generator will keep on adding the html wrappers for the default.